# Unity не следует спрайт оружия за мышкой

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, visual-studio-code, unity3d

Наткнулся на неприятную проблему, смотрел видео зарубежного блогера, и полностью правильно написал весь код, но спрайт никак не двигается за мышкой, чтобы я не делал, вот код. Спрайт должен двигаться стоя на месте, просто куриться в направлении мышки. И еще скриншот на всякий случай приложу. Игра если что 2D.  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float offset;

    private void Update()
    {
        Vector3 difference = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
        float rotZ = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) *  Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotZ + offset);
    }
}
```

Comment: Проверил - всё работает. Посмотрите может в логах ошибку выдал или в иерархии родительский узел выключен? Попробуйте добавить логирование в Update, Debug.Log("Update rotation");

Comment: @norix В логах ошибок нету, но можете подсказать кнопку для вызова лог окна? А то его не появляется в левом нижнем углу, вдруг я его как то отключил. Про родительский узел немного не понял, но по идеи с ним все должно быть хорошо. Логирование добавил.

Comment: Window->General->Console, должно спамить "Update rotation".

Comment: @norix Увидел, благодарю. Да, вылазит какая то одна ошибка постоянно.
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object Weapon.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Weapon.cs:13)

Comment: Возможно не установлена главная камера и падает на строке ... = Camera.main... . Проверьте, что на сцене есть хотя бы одна камера и ей назначен тег "MainCamera". https://ibb.co/NS8dFHK

Comment: @norix Тег сделал, и слава Вам, теперь оружие хотя бы двигается, но не в направлении куда указывает мышь, а просто когда персонаж двигается, сейчас буду пытаться решить как то эту проблему.

Comment: Чтобы оружие целилось по направлению мыши, попробуйте поиграть с полем Offset объекта Weapon. Возможно у автора примера спрайт изначально был повёрнут иначе.

Comment: @norix Я поигрался, оружие просто не следует за мышкой ни при каких условиях. Если персонаж стоит на месте, то и оружие стоит на месте, на мышку наплевать. Но вот если персонаж ходит, оружие как то непроизвольно двигается в разные стороны, но не за мышкой

Comment: @norix https://wdfiles.ru/26d057

Comment: Тут уже не ясно - надо больше инфы, посмотреть сцену целиком. Если очень надо, можете скинуть проект, я гляну.

Comment: @norix Я смог пофиксить, камера была в перспективе, а я так понимаю нужно было поставить Орфографическую, и все заработало. Спасибо Вам большое то что помогали мне в эту ночь :)
Хороших снов!

Comment: Действительно, камера перспективы используется для 3D-миров. На здоровье, желаю успехов.

Answer (score 0):

Сначала нужно присвоить главной камере tag MainCamera. Затем изменить перспективу на Орфографическую, и все заработает.